# Generar consulta con periodo de tiempo especifico

Tags: sql-server

Me gustaría generar un reporte de ventas en el cual se puedan visualizar todas la ventas de la semana, esto sin importar en que día de la semana o mes de año se genere la consulta.

Ejemplo: Genero la consulta hoy "02/06/2019" y que esta me devuelva las ventas a partir de 7 días atrás, esto implicando que tiene que contar desde el mes anterior, osea, todas las ventas entre 27/05/2019 y el 02/06/2019.

Hago uso de la siguiente consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede ver que la segunda consulta no me esa devolviendo ningún registro y esta debería de devolver uno. Los parámetros del DATEADD los tome de documentación de Microsoft donde hacían una consulta de ejemplo como esta: DATEADD("Month", 1,GETDATE());

Gracias por la ayuda...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función DATEPART (wk, getdate()) para obtener el numero de semana a la que pertenece la fecha, getdate() lo sustituyes por tu fecha seleccionada

ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE DATEPART(wk, fecha)= DATEPART (wk, getdate())
```